# Separate words in a column that are separated by space and comma into different columns in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am manipulating a very large movie data set. The data is as below (example)

Ex:

```
title<-c("Interstellar", "Back to the Future", "2001: A Space Odyssey", "The Martian")
genre<-c("Adventure, Drama, SciFi ", "Adventure Comedy SciFi", "Adventure, Sci-Fi", "Adventure Drama Sci-Fi")

movies<-data.frame(title, genre)
```

If you observe in the genre column, certain genres are comma separated and few are space separated. And the word SciFi has two different appearances: SciFi and Sci-Fi. This is my situation in the entire data set that has around 5000 movies.

I am stuck with an appropriate approach for the following results:

1. How to separate the genre of each movie into individual genres. Ex: I want to separate genre for Interstellar as:

---

genre1 = Adventure

---

genre2= Drama

---

genre3=Sci-Fi

---

I've used the following command:

```
movie_genres<-separate(movies, genre, into=c(genre1, genre2, genre3)
```

The above command is separating the word Sci-Fi as two genres (Sci and Fi or only Sci).

2. How to delete the hyphen (-) in the word Sci-Fi across the entire genre so that separate function works well.

OR

3. Is there a work around that adds comma between genres (in genre column) and separate them by comma alone?

Comment: Do you want `separate(movies, genre, into=c("genre1", "genre2", "genre3"), sep = ",?\\s+", fill = "left")` or `movies %>% mutate(genre = str_remove(genre, "-")) %>% separate(genre, into=c("genre1", "genre2", "genre3"), sep = ",?\\s+", fill = "left")`

Comment: Is there any constraint to only include 'Adventure' in genre1, `Comedy/Drama` in genre2 i.e. if the middle one is absent, would it go into genre1.  If it is the first case, you can do `movies %>% mutate(genre = str_remove(genre, "-"), genre1 = str_extract(genre, 'Adventure'), genre2 = str_extract(genre, 'Comedy|Drama'), genre3 = str_extract(genre, 'SciFi'))`

Comment: @akrun no constraints, just want to separate genres appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start by "cleaning" the data. In this case, I'd make the formatting of your genre column consistent (genres column separated, no trailing spaces, ...) and then use separate.

```r
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
title<-c("Interstellar", "Back to the Future", "2001: A Space Odyssey", "The Martian")
genre<-c("Adventure, Drama, SciFi ", "Adventure Comedy SciFi", "Adventure, Sci-Fi", "Adventure Drama Sci-Fi")

movies<-data.frame(title, genre)
movies$genre <- str_replace_all(movies$genre, ",\\s+", ",") 
movies$genre <- str_replace_all(movies$genre, "\\s+$", "") 
movies$genre <- str_replace_all(movies$genre, "\\s+", ",") 
movies$genre <- str_replace_all(movies$genre, "Sci-Fi", "SciFi")
movies$genre
#> [1] "Adventure,Drama,SciFi"  "Adventure,Comedy,SciFi" "Adventure,SciFi"       
#> [4] "Adventure,Drama,SciFi"
separate(movies, genre, into = c("genre1", "genre2", "genre3"))
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [3].
#>                   title    genre1 genre2 genre3
#> 1          Interstellar Adventure  Drama  SciFi
#> 2    Back to the Future Adventure Comedy  SciFi
#> 3 2001: A Space Odyssey Adventure  SciFi   <NA>
#> 4           The Martian Adventure  Drama  SciFi
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect approach. I was stuck on the approach and the word Sci-Fi (SciFi). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What about long format or list columns? Both would let you filter over genres while dealing with multiple misaligned genre columns isn't much fun. For example something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
title<-c("Interstellar", "Back to the Future", "2001: A Space Odyssey", "The Martian")
genre<-c("Adventure, Drama, SciFi ", "Adventure Comedy SciFi", "Adventure, Sci-Fi", "Adventure Drama Sci-Fi")
movies<-data.frame(title, genre)

# long format
movies_long <- movies %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), .before = 1, genre = str_remove_all(genre, "-") %>% str_squish()) %>%  
  separate_rows(genre, sep = ",? ")

movies_long
#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>       id title                 genre    
#>    <int> <chr>                 <chr>    
#>  1     1 Interstellar          Adventure
#>  2     1 Interstellar          Drama    
#>  3     1 Interstellar          SciFi    
#>  4     2 Back to the Future    Adventure
#>  5     2 Back to the Future    Comedy   
#>  6     2 Back to the Future    SciFi    
#>  7     3 2001: A Space Odyssey Adventure
#>  8     3 2001: A Space Odyssey SciFi    
#>  9     4 The Martian           Adventure
#> 10     4 The Martian           Drama    
#> 11     4 The Martian           SciFi

# filter by genre
movies_long %>% filter(genre == "Adventure")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>      id title                 genre    
#>   <int> <chr>                 <chr>    
#> 1     1 Interstellar          Adventure
#> 2     2 Back to the Future    Adventure
#> 3     3 2001: A Space Odyssey Adventure
#> 4     4 The Martian           Adventure
```

```r
# list columns, genre column will be filled with lists of genres
movies_lst <- movies %>% 
  mutate(genre = str_remove_all(genre, "-") %>% str_squish() %>% str_split(",? ")) %>% 
  as_tibble()

movies_lst
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   title                 genre    
#>   <chr>                 <list>   
#> 1 Interstellar          <chr [3]>
#> 2 Back to the Future    <chr [3]>
#> 3 2001: A Space Odyssey <chr [2]>
#> 4 The Martian           <chr [3]>

# can be filtered with e.g. map_lgl and for output can be concatenated to a single string
movies_lst %>% filter(
  map_lgl(genre, ~ all(c("Drama", "SciFi") %in% .x))) %>% 
  mutate(genre = map_chr(genre, ~paste(.x , collapse = ", ")))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   title        genre                  
#>   <chr>        <chr>                  
#> 1 Interstellar Adventure, Drama, SciFi
#> 2 The Martian  Adventure, Drama, SciFi
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for help. But I wanted to separate them rather than filtering because I want to find the number of movies in each genre (group) and my actual data set is huge.

Answer (score 1):

This approach lists genres separately in their columns and expands automatically when new genres occur.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

movies %>% 
  mutate(genre = strsplit(genre, ", | ")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(genre = list(sub("-", "", genre))) %>% 
  unnest(genre) %>% 
  group_by(genre) %>% 
  mutate(grp = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  arrange(grp) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=grp, names_prefix="genre_", values_from=genre)
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  title                 genre_1   genre_2 genre_3 genre_4
  <chr>                 <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1 Interstellar          Adventure NA      Drama   SciFi  
2 Back to the Future    Adventure Comedy  NA      SciFi  
3 2001: A Space Odyssey Adventure NA      NA      SciFi  
4 The Martian           Adventure NA      Drama   SciFi
```

Comment: This is good but the issue is my actual data set is very large. I used your method to my data set and it doubled the number of columns (created almost 20 new columns for genres). But thanks for the help. Much appreciated.